# How to populating two dropdowns at once using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, html-select, dropdown

I'm creating two dropdown fields from 2 two tables in my database (States and Cities). The Cities tables are linked to each states. I converted the data from both tables to Json using php. I use Ajax to populate both select dropdown as well. Now, I want to filter the cities dropdown when a user select a state from the state dropdown. I'm using the code below and it's working fine, except, it's adding one empty option field after each populated option fields. Any help?

```
function State() {
    $('#statedd1').empty();
    $('#statedd1').append("<option value='0'>- Select State -</option>");
    $('#citydd1').append("<option value='0'>- Select City -</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"states.php",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#statedd1').empty();
            $('#statedd1').append("<option value='0'>- Select State -</option>");
            $.each(data,function (index, item) {
                $('#statedd1').append('<option value="'+ item.State_ID +'">'+ item.State_Name +'<option>');
            });
        },complete: function() {}
    });
}

function City(State_ID) {
    $('#citydd1').empty();
    $('#citydd1').append("<option>Loading...</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"cities.php?Id="+State_ID,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#storedd1').empty();
            $('#storedd1').append("<option value='0'>- Select City -</option>");
            $.each(data,function (index, item) {
                $('#citydd1').append('<option value="'+ item.CityID +'">'+ item.CityName +'<option>');
            });
        },complete: function() {}
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        State();
        $("#statedd1").change(function() {
            var State_ID = $("#statedd1").val();
            City(State_ID);
        });
    });
```

```
<p><select id="statedd1"></select></p>
<br><br>
<p><select id="citydd1" multiple></select></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing a / in the second option tag < /option> in your append line

Comment: Oh wow! that was it @Martin Julyan. Thank you so much. Just the little thing and I've been struggling all week trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. Hahaha